# How to redirect a old URL using web.config (IIS)

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, iis7, windows

I'm still very new to using URL rewrites and redirects and I'm having some problems on something I thought was quite simple...

I've just rebuilt a website and want to redirect the old URLs to the new ones.

For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/about.asp?lang=1<br>
```

Should now be:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/content.asp?id=100230&title=about&langid=1
```

Unfortunately, everything I've tried is giving me errors or simply does nothing.

Here is one rule I tried:

```
<rule name="redirectoldabout" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="( .*)" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.com/about\.asp\?lang=1$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/content.asp?id=100230&title=about&langid=1" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but I get an error back:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the 301 in your web.config for now.

Enter this in your **global.asax** file near the bottom:

```
    Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains(
"http://www.mydomain.com/about.asp?lang=1")) Then

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status =
            "301 Moved Permanently"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
            Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(
                "http://www.mydomain.com/about.asp?lang=1",
                "http://www.mydomain.com/content.asp?id=100230&title=about&
                 langid=1"))

    End If
        End Sub
```

Save and upload.  This will take care of the issue.

If you're more comfortable editing your web.config, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228910/url-rewriting-redirect-one-page-to-another) on SE for more information.

Comment: thanks very much for your reply...
i would rather use the web.config as i already have some redirects there (redirecting from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com for example)...
i checked the link you provided to stackoverflow and found something there which helped...
my working rule :

'<rule name="About Us redirect from old site" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="about.asp" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="content.asp?id=100230" />
</rule>'

Comment: Glad to hear you worked things out!